# How do I group similar emails (same subject) as a thread inside Mail 10.3 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5?

Tags: macos, email

In Yosemite, the Mac Mail app grouped emails with same subject into a thread. Not in this version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure View → Organise by Conversation is checked.

Comment: It already is. Yet emails with same subject aren't threaded?